# How can I add resources to a C# project in SharpDevelop?

Tags: c#, image, resources, project, sharpdevelop

When I want so select an image, the project resource is empty:

[image: here]

How can I add resource there?

Comment: Just to be sure: have you read https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Using-Resources

Comment: @C.Evenhuis  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, I used the .resx file:

1. Create a new resource file to your project (Project > Add > New Item > Misc > Empty resource file).
2. Right click on the **empty list** (white space) in the resource editor > Add Files,
   choose the file
3. How the files gets added depends on the file type, images are added
   as System.Drawing.Bitmap, binary files as byte array.

Assume we add  "Image.png". To access the files, use this code:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager("Namespace.ResourceFile", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) resources.GetObject("Image"); //image without extension
myButton.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
```

Namespace is the root namespace of your application, ResourceFile the name of the .resx file (without the .resx extension). If the .resx file is inside a subfolder in the project, use "Namespace.SubfolderName.ResourceFile".
Make sure your image fits the Control.Size, the property BackgroungImage does not resize the image.
The resx file act like a folder, it wil cointain your resources.

Answer (score 2):

There is more strightforward solution to your (@tomyforever) answer.

1. create an empty resource file (i.e. "gfx.resx") and add there the file "Image.png" the default name should be "Image" here, but you can rename it, of course
2. set the Custom Tool property of the resource file (from dropdown menu) to `ResXFileCodeGenerator` (sometimes it is added automatically)
3. now it is visible in the UI Project resource, or just use `myButton.BackgroundImage = gfx.Image;` in the code

You [should not use Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=netframework-4.8) if you know the assymbly name at compile time.